# Facebook Graph API of me doesn't return the address field

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

The returned field

```
{
"first_name" = john;
gender = male;
id = xxxxxxxx;
"last_name" = doe;
link = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxxxx";
locale = "en_US";
name = "john doe";
timezone = "-7";
"updated_time" = "2012-03-31T20:48:55+0000";
```

}

It's missing the email address field.  I login to my facebook account and check the email address field is there.

Comment: ask for email permission

Answer (score 0):

Are you authenticating as yourself for that API call? All of that data looks public.

The API does allow access to the currently signed-in user's email address (via the `email` parameter), but you must be authenticated to have access to it, and you must request [explicit permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) for it as well.

From [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/):

> You can ask for the following permissions for users and friends in the scope parameter as part of the authentication process.
>
> ...
>
> email: Provides access to the user's primary email address in the email property. Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply both with Facebook policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act.

Comment: I did a facebooklogin and did login as myself then I request graph api for my own info. Joe Doe is sub name for me.